# Socket.io not globally available when using Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, socket.io

Everything was working fine before adding webpack. Here's my current config *(below)*. Inside login.js, there's a window.onload function, then shortly after there's a socket.on function, which is now breaking the program. It seems as if "socket" is not globally available to the other files after adding webpack.

Here's the error code I receive in console when running my app:
 *"login.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: socket.on is not a function at window.onload (login.js:1)"*

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

**webpack.config**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        scripts: './src/scripts.js',
        login: './src/login.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    }, 
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/js/'
    }
}
```

**Script section of index.html**

```
  <script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/login.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

Worked fine before, so I don't believe there's an issue here:

**Server**

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

**Client**
scripts.js (not in a function, globally declared):

```
const socket = io();
let socketid;
socket.on('connect', () =>  socketid = socket.io.engine.id);
```

login.js (inside window.onload function):

```
socket.on('check email', () => {
        setTimeout(() => refreshPage(), 7500);
        popupbox({
            titletext: 'Verify email', messagetext: 'A verification link has been sent, please verify your email address within 24 hours.', 
            okaytext: 'Okay', okayfunction: () => refreshPage(),
            customcolor: "#007C5B"
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have to show the relevant code where you create you instance of socket io client, the place where you `import`/`require`, and where you call `socket.on`

Comment: I didn't mean the server side `import`/`require`. I mean the client side one, where do you set you  `socket`  variable?

Comment: should you really `exclude: /node_modules/` in your rule?
I have a working socket.io-webpack-combo without it, could be youre just packing your frontend without socket.io altogether

Comment: It's to make moving the project around easier and compiling faster, since they're easily created with npm install and it's not code I'd be editing. But I tried removing that line to see if it'd work and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const socket` is local to the module defined by `scripts.js` and is not a global variable. And as of that it does not exists in `login.js`.

While it would be possible to make it global, the whole idea of modules and bundlers is to encapsulate your code into small logical parts and that you don't need to pollute the global namespace.

So you need to pass your `socket` in some way to `login.js`. How you want to do that depends on the overall structure of the project.

One way could be to export it in your module, and `import`/`require` it in your `login.js` or where ever else you need it.

**socket.js**

```
const socket = io();
let socketid;
socket.on('connect', () =>  socketid = socket.io.engine.id);

module.exports.socket = socket; // export the socket

// could also look that way:
// module.exports = socket;
// the require would then look like that:
// const socket = require('./socket.js');
```

**login.js**

```
const socket = require('./socket.js').socket;

socket.on('check email', () => {
        setTimeout(() => refreshPage(), 7500);
        popupbox({
            titletext: 'Verify email', messagetext: 'A verification link has been sent, please verify your email address within 24 hours.', 
            okaytext: 'Okay', okayfunction: () => refreshPage(),
            customcolor: "#007C5B"
        });
    });
```

Comment: You had some typos (moudle), but I was able to use what you suggested to get past the error, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use **global**  to declare your variables globaly like

```
global.io = io();
```

And the use the io variable in other files like

```
io.on('connect',...)
```

Might be it would help someone in future

Comment: It's true that using global would work, but you really should only use them if there is no other way around it. E.g. if you need to pass data to a 3rd party script that expects it to be set as a global.